# Remove matching character in the first line and all characters below in other lines

Tags: bash

I have some strings

```
M-AA-
-AG--
M---G
```

I want to remove `-` in the first line and all characters corresponding to the position of the `-` in other lines, to get

```
MAA
-G-
M--
```

May I know how to do it in the simplest bash command?

Comment: Removing `'-'` in the first line is understandable, but how does *"all characters below in other lines"* work? Why choose to remove `'A'` in line 2 and not `'G'`? What have you tried? `awk` will be the tools to use, but you could do it with just bash (much slower).

Comment: That makes more sense.

Comment: I am using this solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557611/using-awk-remove-columns-that-are-on-the-first-line/557793#557793 but this time the input are strings without separated by tab (i.e. not columns).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk [1], if you set the field separator to the empty string, you can iterate over each character:

```bash
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ""}
    NR == 1 {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "-") remove[i]}
    {for (i in remove) $i = ""; print}
' file
```

---

[1] - at least gawk, mawk and the default awk on recent MacOS.